# В блоке "Поделиться" неверно отражается кодировка

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Разместил блок "Поделиться" из конструктора яндекса. Разместил внизу сайта [сайтвсрок.рф](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA.%D1%80%D1%84)

При наведении курсора мыши на иконку "Мой мир" выходит подсказка иероглифами. При нажатии на "Мой мир" - в описание из дескрипшина попадают так же непонятные иероглифы.

Вот ссылка: [сайтвсрок.рф](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA.%D1%80%D1%84)

Answer (score 2):

Кодировка сайта указана как win1251, а скрипт от Яндекса юникодный, вот и получаются "кракозябры". Исправьте кодировку на сайте, будет меньше проблем.

Comment: кодировку на сайте править не буду. ранее был скрипт - там в яваскриптах они сами прописывали юникод, почему теперь такие проблемы?

Comment: Попробуйте поиграться с `charset` в `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`, хотя ваша позиция выглядит странно. Указание кодировки у страницы с кириллицей в utf-8 - уже давно устоявшийся прием, почему вы его игнорируете?

Comment: @Евгений Дело конечно Ваше, кодировку на самом сайте моно и не менять, просто меня смутило на сайте: `<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
` В комментарии выше Вам подсказали, что можно указать кодировку для скрипта при подключении.

Comment: добавил в скрипт charset="utf-8" и убрал вверху задвоенную кодовую стриницу. Всех благодарю за ответ.